# How to switch app only on active display (not on both displays at the same time)

Tags: display, application-switcher

I have an external monitor connected to my Mac Pro. Both displays have separate Spaces. I usually have 2 Firefox windows on both displays (1 on my Mac and 1 on my external monitor) and 2 programming IDEs on both displays.

My goal is to be able to have a programming IDE open on an external monitor and Firefox open on my Mac at the same time. The problem is that Mac os changes the active application (with CMD+TAB or mouse) on both displays. This problem occurs only when the application is present on both screens. If I have IDE on an external monitor and Firefox on Mac then it works ok. But when I have 2xIDE and 2xFirefox on both displays then as mentioned above MacOS will switch on both of them.

As a workaround I only came up with an idea to minimise one of the windows, then the app switcher will not switch to it.

Comment: You *might* get some joy from Mission Control > "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows…" but I can't test as 'separate spaces' messes up my workflow.

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried that but it didn't help. Still the app switches on both displays

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're fighting a paradigm. macOS was never designed for one app to be on more than one Space. [Fullscreen has further blurred this since its inception]

Comment: I would say having 2 IDEs on 2 displays is quite common among developers. Having an IDE next to a browser as well. I'm no expert on UX, but this kinda looks like a bad design decision.

Comment: Blame fullscreen. Since its implementation no further improvement has ever been made to Spaces. Still, UX choice good/bad, that's how it works. Personally I cannot stand using 'Displays have separate Spaces' so it doesn't hurt my workflow, I'm used to my displays all shifting in unison. I also never use cmd/tab, I use the command to move to a specific Space instead. I've also been using multiple displays since the 90s, so I've seen this implemented in several ways, good & bad. For me, the worst ever implementation was fullscreen.